# How to add an item in specific column in listViewItem

Tags: c#, listviewitem

I have list all item using `foreach` by its filename. Now, how can I add in the second column the path of each files listed in the first column? I have already add a column or collection on the properties.

```
    foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(path, fileType, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        listViewFiles.Items.Add(fileName);
    }
```

Comment: What platform are you developing against - is it web or WinForms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Set up List View
listViewFiles.View = View.Details;
listViewFiles.Columns.Clear();
listViewFiles.Columns.Add("File name");
listViewFiles.Columns.Add("File path");

// Populate with files and file paths
foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(path, fileType, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    listView1.Items.Add(fileName).SubItems.Add(new FileInfo(fileName).DirectoryName);
}
```

EDIT:

Personally, I find it easier to instantiate a DirectoryInfo for this kind of thing, it populate lots of useful fields for you.  So you could do:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles(fileType, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    listViewFiles.Items.Add(fi.Name).SubItems.Add(fi.DirectoryName);
```

Comment: Thanks! But it still lists the items on the first column. Am I missing something?

Comment: I've just tested this and it's working - are you sure you've set up your ListView with multiple columns?  You can do this in the Visual Studio interface, or with code - I'll add some code into my answer.

Comment: It worked for mine too, I just missed to set up another column. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how you can extract the path (without filename), create a FileInfo object and read out its DirectoryName property:

```
var fi = new FileInfo(filename);
var dir = fi.DirectoryName;
```

Comment: I don't think this was clear in your question - have modified answer to include this.

Comment: @CarlosP this is right. We'll see, what the question was exactly ;-)

Comment: Your answer shows only how to obtain a directory name from a file path.  It's unclear, but I thought the OP was also asking how to get this into the second column of a ListView - hence why the title of the question is 'How to add an item in specific column of listViewItem'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SubItems:

```
foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(path, fileType, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filepath);        
    listViewFiles.Items.Add(fi.Name).SubItems.Add(fi.DirectoryName);
}
```

EDIT: I modify it to have filename and file directory

Comment: I think I just got there ahead of you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(path, fileType, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
    listViewFiles.Items.Add(fileName, directoryName);
}
```

See the [ListViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/faw83h4f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructors for more info.